# how to script a simple count if

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to find this but I could not figure out the answer on the other questions that were posted. I have two conditions that are used to sort data. The months of the year and if it is ranked 1, 2, or 3.

what i need is on a summary page to count how many inputs there are for each month with specific rank

I hope this all makes sense I tried to clarify the best I can, I am really overwhelmed with this and have no type of coding/scripting experience. 
Thanks for any help!

I have used the codes below to return the dates and ranks of the data and to extract the month. 
It then uses those months in if statements to put on a summary page. What I do not know how to do is from here put a count formula in it. Like with this code here I want it to be similar to the formula if=month=1 and tiers(ranks)= 1 then count (it cant add because if it adds, when the page updates it will add to numbers that it already counted)

```
    for(var i =8;i<=j;i++) { //loops through a data table to see dates and ranks
    var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
    var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();
    var month = new Date(dates).getMonth()+1;

    switch (true){
      case((month==1)): //if it is january
         if(tiers==1)  // if it is rank 1
           jan1.setValue(); 
         if(tiers==2)
           jan2.setValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function

```
function countTiersByMonth ( dataTable, firstline, lastline ) {
    var result = [ [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0], [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0], [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0], [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0] ];
    var dates;
    var tiers;
    var month;
    for(i = firstline; i<=lastline; i++) { 
        dates = dataTable.getRange(i,22).getValue();
        tiers = dataTable.getRange(i,14).getValue();
        month = new Date(dates).getMonth();

        switch (tiers){ // we filter by tiers because it seems that you only care about
                        // tiers 1, 2, 3 wheras you care about all the months
            case 1: 
            case 2:
            case 3:
                result[month][tiers-1]++; //+1 for the respective tier
                                          //  of the respective month
                break;      //other tiers are ignored
        };
    };
    return result;
};
```

This takes the data table, the first significant line (8 in your example) and the last relevant line ("j" in your example) and outputs an array with 12 elements, one for each month, that contain 3 elements each, one for each tier you wanted to count. 
If you want, lets say the results for May, you call

```
tierlist = countTiersByMonth(oppwon, 8, j) // We do the counting here
print(tierlist[4][0]) // arrays start at 0, so May -> [4], Tier 1 -> [0]
print(tierlist[4][1]) // May, Tier 2
print(tierlist[4][2]) // May, Tier 3
```

Comment: im sorry i dont have much experience with this...  the [0,0,0] for each variable doing what exactly?  I understand the firstline, lastline, is this just locating the cells? where is the counting being done?

Comment: Ah sorry, I guess I should have explained it a bit better. The [0,0,0] are [#Tier1, #Tier2, #Tier3] for each month. We set them to 0 before we start counting. In the for loop, we go through every line in the data table, and whenever we find a Tier 1,2 or 3, we up the counter for the tier we find and output the array at the end.

Comment: Added an example to the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setValue in the loop, you should consider doing the counting within variable/s and only setValue once the loop is completed.

Some suggested code per below:

```
for(var i =8;i<=j;i++) { //loops through a data table to see dates and ranks
var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();
var month = new Date(dates).getMonth()+1;
var countTiers = {}; //count by tiers of months

countTiers[`m${month}`][`t${tiers}`]++;
```

You will end up getting an object like e.g. {m1: {t1: 2, t2: 1}} after the loop.

Then you can setValue in the desired column for the final count.

Comment: Im confused about what this part is actually doing? countTiers[`m${month}`][`t${tiers}`]++;   am I supposed to substitute some of these symbols for something else? cant seem to figure it out